# Automate Chrome To Phone/ Android Intent C2DM feature in windows application

Tags: android, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, android-c2dm

I have a Android mobile. I also have a application running on my laptop. Its a windows application. I have chrome installed in my laptop with chrome to phone extension already installed. Now When I open a link in the browser and click on the extension I get a android intent or a notification to my mobile. Now I want to automate this.

I mean to say that my windows application written in .net must be able to do this operation for me. I mean on some validations done I need to get a notification or some kind of intent to my mobile. If this has to be dome manually, it is like application will give a message box alert. As soon as I see the alert message i open chrome (or already opened) and then open up a link say "www.google.com" and then click on "chrome to phone" extension. I want this to be done automatically. Is this possible? If so how?

Please let me know if there are any other ideas or tweaks that can be done to achieve a similar operation. Basically i am trying to get a alert from my windows application to my android mobile. Any kind of help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way Chrome to Phone works is through a mid tier provider. In this case it is AppEngine.

If you analyse the source code, the only thing the extension does is post to a service (http://chrometophone.appspot.com/_ah/channel/jsapi). So if you want to imitate the same thing to your windows application, you do the same request.

Source code is open, don't be afraid snooping around :) The source code is located here http://code.google.com/p/chrometophone/.